# Replace WordPress theme from local host without losing production site data

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I have locally built a new theme for my website which is a Woocommerce store. I only added a few products to the local version to test but now I want to add the new edited theme to the production site.

What's the best solution to moving a new customised theme to a production site without losing the user and product data?

Comment: What does this have to do with content stored in the database to begin with? Just upload the theme folder via FTP, and then activate the theme ...?

Comment: Because I have customised the theme to what I want, but have not added all the products from the production site. Therefore I presume some data is stored on the database.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the theme (and no data that would be stored in the database), you can simply upload the theme folder to the server (into the "themes" folder) via FTP and then select the theme in the backend.

Comment: Even if I have modified the theme? Thanks for the response :)

Comment: If your theme is self-created, yes. But if you modified a theme you downloaded or bought (which isn't clear from your description), it's better to create a child theme and upload that, since a downloaded theme will one day probably be updated, and then your changes would be lost – which doesn't happen with  a child theme.

Comment: Yea I've done all that but, just transferring the theme files via FTP does not pull over the new pages, uploads and theme settings that I have made locally?

Comment: Well ,those are things that are saved in the database and are not parts of the theme.

Comment: But there is the "export data" function in the "tools" section, which can export/import different types of data.

Comment: Yup and that's the issue I am having.